# How to convert timestamp to HH:MM:SS format using python and graph the information?

Tags: python, datetime, timestamp

I am trying to use timestamp information to graph. 
However, when I convert the number into hh:mm:ss. It does not work.

I have tried this:

```
 timestamp = [dt.strptime(str(datetime.timedelta(seconds=round(t/1000))),'%H:%M:%S') for t in timestamp1]
```

[image]

Also I tried this 
    timestamp = [dt.strftime(dt.strptime(str(datetime.timedelta(seconds=round(t / 1000))), '%H:%M:%S'), '%H:%M:%S') for t in timestamp]

[image]

However, it is possible to see the list with the new values. However, I have problems with the graphs and these new values.

Can anybody help me?

Comment: Can you add an example of the container  `timestamp1`?
It's a unix timestamp, correct?

Comment: Sure, timestamp1= [502883,....]

Answer (score 0):

Try using this and make sure to import the time module!

```
timestamp = [time.strftime('%H:%M:%S',  time.gmtime(t/1000)) for t in timestamp1]
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try it and I will let you know !

Answer (score 0):

In your code you're using [datetime.strptime(date_string, format)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime) function, it's main use is to parse time strings in order to create datetime object.

In order to get a parsed string of a desired format you should use [date.strftime(format)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.strftime) function instead.
So basically in your code you can only add it and should get the wanted result:

```
import datetime
from datetime import datetime as dt

timestamp = [dt.strftime(dt.strptime(str(datetime.timedelta(seconds=round(t / 1000))), '%H:%M:%S'), '%H:%M:%S') for t in timestamp1]
```

I'm not sure what was your input and desired output, but you could also use [date.fromtimestamp(timestamp)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.fromtimestamp) for the parsing of timestamps

Comment: Thank you. It works with few data but I cannot understand why graph is not working with lots of data. I would like to share the new graph. However, I don't know how to do it (I tried ctrl + g).

Comment: @CarolinaF. it looks like you have a problem with the xticks frequency (too dense) in your graphs, you should sparsify them.
You didn't add the code you use for the graphs but assuming it's pyplot you can use the [xticks()](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.xticks.html#matplotlib-pyplot-xticks) or you can use [locator_params(axis='both', tight=None, **kwargs)](https://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.locator_params)
But, you should add the code if you want a more specific answer